# How does yacc work,can you explain it section by section?

Tags: compiler-construction, syntax, yacc

How does this tiny yacc programe work?

What I know so far:

`%{...%}` is definition
`%% ... %%` is rule,but how to interpret the rule?
and stuff after `%%` is function definition.
What's the section `%token INTEGER` between `%}` and `%%` ?

```
%{
#include <stdlib.h>
int yylex(void);
void yyerror(char *);
%}
%token INTEGER
%left '+' '-'
%left '*' '/'
%%
program:
program expr '\n' { printf("%d\n", $2); }
|
;
expr:
INTEGER { $$ = $1; }
| expr '*' expr { $$ = $1 * $3; }
| expr '/' expr { $$ = $1 / $3; }
| expr '+' expr { $$ = $1 + $3; }
| expr '-' expr { $$ = $1 - $3; }
;
%%
void yyerror(char *s) {
printf("%s\n", s);
}
int main(void) {
yyparse();
return 0;
}
```

**UPDATE**

What I don't understand:

```
program:
program expr '\n' { printf("%d\n", $2); }
|
;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `expr:` means an expr is one of the following options, which are separated by | below.  If it can be seen as an `INTEGER` token, then it takes the first one.  If it can be seen as an `expr` followed by the `*` character followed by an `expr` then it takes the second option and so on.  `$$` is the default return value, and `$1` is the first token, `$2` the second on and on.

So if it were parsing `5 + 6`, it sees it as expr '+' expr, so it takes the 4th definition. It returns 11 as an `expr`, so then it matches 11 as an `INTEGER` token and assigns 11 as the return value.

If we were parsing a program token followed by `5 + 6`, it would do the same thing to get program 11, then take the program expr rule and call the c code which would print to the screen.

Left means that operator is left associative. As in `a + b + c` = `(a + b) + c`. The operators on the same line have the same precedence, and those below it have lower precedence.

I admittedly haven't used yacc in a while so feel free to tell me I'm totally wrong.

UPDATE:

yacc generates c code, so you can put your own code directly into it.  So as it's parsing, if it sees a "program expr", then it can directly input the code in the { } into the generated code.

Answer (score 1):

There are total five phases of compiler namely:

1. lexical analysis
2. syntax analysis
3. semantic analysis (intermediate code generation-optional )
4. Code optimization
5. Code generation

The lex and YACC (yet another compiler compiler ) are both the Unix utilities to generate a program.lexer is responsible for matching the words in given program and when the match is found it stores the values in yylex and return in the form of tokens to lexer. yacc is basically a parser which takes the tokens and builds a tree from it to check the syntax of the program.The tokens are build by lexer and they are declared in yacc specification file.
so the y.tab.h file is included in lex program .

The above program contains a token INTEGER which is returned by lexer. The yacc program should contain a start state ...the "program" is the start state every program should contain atleast one start state... The yacc rules are in format  rule  {action} 
.In above program "program expr '\n' " represents that the program can contain expression and then a newline character. i.e 5+4 'enter key' represents an expression for that we have written a expr '+' expr ;here expr can be integer in this case 5 and 4 so we include that rule also by writing expr: INTEGER
....for addition or any other role the LHS of expression is represented by $$ and  RHS by $1 ,$2 , $3...so on.hence expr: expr '+' expr { $$ = $1 + $3;} ......

Comment: This looks like it's quite a good answer although it would be clearer if it were formatted better. I've cleaned up the bits I can for now without changing what you wrote too much, but you might want to take a look at http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help as well.

Comment: The lexical value is not stored in `yylex`. *yacc* does not build a tree. Semantic analysis does not include intermediate code generation. `program` is the target symbol, not the start state. Too much erroneous waffle here.